# How can a jade partial address relative links from templates within both directories and subdirectories?

Tags: templates, pug, relative-path, subdirectory

I'm using [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) with [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to generate a static html prototype but having problems with relative links to assets like css files from jade templates located in subdirectories.

As this is a prototype and team members should be able to take a look at it quickly,

- the files should be usable out of the box by using just a browser with no further configuration
- no server is used
- the files should be viewable on different machines

### Project Structure

The source folder structure is like this:

```
src
|
|--first.jade
|
|--subdirectory
|  `--second.jade
|
|--templates
|  |--layout.jade
|  `--head.jade
|
`--css
   `--styles.css
```

first.jade and second.jade both [extend](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/) layout.jade.

layout.jade [includes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) the partial head.jade, which contains a relative link to styles.css:

```
head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/styles.css')
```

gulp generates this structure (which is how I want the project to be structured, so this shouldn't change):

```
build
|
|--first.html
|
|--subdirectory
|  `--second.html
|
`--css
   `--styles.css
```

### Problems with this approach

1. The relative link to the css does not work for second.html as it is
   in a subdirectory. The link in the rendered html is

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`

   but it should be this in order to work:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">`
2. I have to use different extend statements in first.jade and
   second.jade, which is not a real problem but rather annoying.

   first.jade:

   `extends templates/layout.jade`

   second.jade:

   `extends ../templates/layout.jade`

### Possible solution (which quite doesn't fit)

One solution to problem one could be to use a [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) in head.jade like this:

`base(href='/Users/myusername/build/')`

This works perfectly, but only on my machine, and only if I leave the project folder at the current location. This won't work for anyone else as the path used in the base tag will not be found on their machine.

### Question

Is there some clever way to solve problem one with just using jade? Bonus for problem two...

It seems to me that the problem at hand should be a very common one, so I might have overlooked it in the docs or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with: Using the base tag in combination with jade variables.

head.jade now includes a block containing a variable to set the base path with a default value of '.':

```
block basetag
  -var base = '.'

head
  base(href='#{base}')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/styles.css')
```

This works for all templates in the root directory by default.

For all templates in a subdirectory, the base variable can be set to '../' like this:

```
extends ../templates/layout.jade
block basetag
  -var base = '../'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got function to make relative path from dividing slash with current path.

```
  -
    // Count depth directory hierarchy
    var depth = (relativePath.match(/\//g) || []).length;
    var relativeRoot = new Array(depth + 1).join( '../' );
```

[visit my repo](https://github.com/kohki-shikata/gulp-pug-test/blob/imp-relative-path/src/_includes/_layout.pug#L4#L5)